# Print all lines in "file2" which have line number stored in "file1" $2

Tags: shell, unix, awk, gawk

File1:

```
count    line_num  
xy       55  
ab       67
```

File2:

```
a|b|c  
d|e|f
```

I want to print 55, 67 line numbers of file2

am trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh  
while read file_name; do  
    line_num=`echo $file_name | awk '{print $2}'`  
    awk 'NR==$line_num{print;exit}' file2 >> file3.txt  
done < file1
```

but it's not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to read the line numbers in a loop and `sed` to print out the specific lines:

`while read a; do sed -n ${a}p f2.txt; done < <(awk 'NR>1{print$2}' f1.txt)`

If you have a bigger file, performance can be an issue as Ed pointed out, in that case you can use `awk` alone:

`awk 'NR==FNR{if(NR>1)l[$2]=1;next}{if(l[FNR])print $0}' f1.txt f2.txt`

Another way, is to use `xargs`:

`awk 'NR>1{print $2}' f1.txt | xargs -n1 -I {} sed -n {}p f2.txt`

Comment: Make sure you read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) first.

Comment: Yea, if it's a modestly sized file it will be  alot slower than plain `awk`.

Comment: Right so why **EVER** do it since it's not even any briefer than an awk script. btw never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` (indistinguishable in some fonts) and so obfuscates your code.

Comment: Logically it can be easier to interpret if someone doesn't know `awk`, and there are many things that the shell has to offer that `awk` doesn't.

Comment: I strongly disagree that that shell loop is easier to understand than the idiomatic awk solution (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36872782/1745001) but YMMV I suppose. In any case, if someone is doing a task like this and doesn't know awk then they need to learn how to do it in awk as it's the right approach. Of course there are many things the shell can do that awk can't but the guys who invented shell to do those many things also invented awk for the shell to call when it needs to do this one thing of manipulating text. In UNIX you just use the right tool for each job, that's all.

Comment: Thanks Danischewski and Ed. It's pretty efficient solution instead of using while loop. As the file size is in GB's while loop was taking quite 15-20 sec whereas this awk command did it in milliseconds. Now, I need to compare the output of this awk command with file2 and supress all common lines between the two. Please suggest whether 'comm -3' command can be used for the same and how would i pass the output of this awk as second parameter of comm in a single line command!

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{line[$2]; next} FNR in line' file1 file2
```

We iterate the first file and store second column in a map called `line` (we could ignore the first line which is the header by doing `NR>1` but since it doesn't contain numbers we don't need to). Once the first file is loaded in map, we iterate the second file and print out lines that are in our map. `NR` and `FNR` are awk variables that remembers the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use **sed** to construct a **sed** one-liner (in the case of *file1* it'd output and run `sed -n "55p;67p;" file2`):

```
sed -n "$(sed -n '2~1{s/.* //;s/.*/&p/p}' file1)" file2
```

A good advertisement for **awk**, alas!